# Email redirected to Gmail contains failed SPF

Tags: email, email-server, redirect, spf, gmail

I have an email account on my domain, e.g `adrian@mysite.com`
And on my dedicated server mysite.com I redirect messages from `adrian@mysite.com to adrian@gmail.com`

Now, if an external user like `john@example.com` sends me an email to `adrian@mysite.com`, it properly lands in Gmail but in spam and Gmail headers says that SPF failed, because `example.com` doesn't designate `mysite.com` as a permitted sender.

Is there something I can do about this? It doesn't sound right, `mysite.com` should not claim that is sending email for `john@example.com`, it should just be labeled somehow as a redirect (`from adrian@mysite.com to adrian@gmail.com`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe (passing envelope sender through unchanged) is traditionally how mail forwarding has behaved. After all if there's a problem with delivery that's where errors need to go.

To avoid SPF issues forwarding services can use SRS[1](http://www.libsrs2.org/) to construct a new (local) envelope sender address which routes to the original.

Comment: Thanks. So, also... because I am receiving many spam messages to `adrian@mysite.com` then Gmail sees me as a spammer, right ? Gmail sees spam email from server `mysite.com` TO `adrian@gmail.com` with various sender address. Is that correct ?

Comment: if the ratio of spam to non-spam messages coming from your server is high (no matter where the messages originally came from) then that's going to negatively impact your server's sending reputation. The right thing to do (IMHO) is filter for spam at the server doing the redirect and not accept or forward messages which appear to be spam.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same thing, that confirms it. At server (Plesk) I use Spamassassin and zen.spamhaus.org, is there a better way to stop spam and do not forward it to my Gmail and do not bounce back to faked sender address ?

Comment: yes set google up to POP3 to download the email from your server to gmail instead, https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en